# SSIS Package -Could not load package because of error 0xC0014062

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am getting below error on Window server 2008.

I am using 32 bit DTexec from C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\90\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe

Could not load package because of error 0xC0014062.
Description: The LoadFromSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80004005 (An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.). The SQL statement that was issued has failed.

Comment: You have Windows Server 2008 and you are executing an SSIS package using the SQL Server 2005 version of `dtexec` You are running a package that resides within the msdb and encountering this error message. Tell us more. Are you connecting to a 2005 instance? Has this ever worked? What are the exact arguments you're passing to dtexec? etc

Answer (score 5):

If it's SQL2016...

1. click on job
2. choose properties
3. Steps-->Edit-->Execution Options
4. Check use 32-bit runtime

Comment: Karl, this solution worked for me though it is difficult to understand why.  SSIS is installed from a 64 bit install file on a 64 bit copy of SQL on a 64 bit machine.  It's possible the download package from MS is mistakenly only a 32 bit package library.  Otherwise, this makes no sense.  Also noted: initially the IS packages work in 64 bit mode, but fail after about a day after being connected to the network.  [On an AWS network.]

Comment: I discovered the same but oddly, this 64 bit version worked for the last 45 days.  Last night the jobs began to fail without an explanation.   I put them back to 32 bit.   The day before I'd tweaked the job and this changed it back to 64 bit - strange.  So, it had been set for 32 bit  - but reset itself to 64 bit on a tweak.

Comment: this solution helped me

Comment: Jamie, it's a feature of ssis that it changes important parts of your code without asking.  I've reset 50 unicode character advanced and had it set all of it back to the default.

Answer (score 2):

To get more information about this error, do the following:

1. Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
2. Go to SQL Server Agent -> Jobs -> Right-click on the particular one that you has the
   issue, and click Properties.
3. Go to Steps -> Choose the step -> Click Edit -> Under Advanced check: Include step output in history.
4. Retry to run the Job on more time.
5. Right click on the Job and choose History that will give you more information about the error.

Some solutions:

- A missing "/" at the package of the Job, see the following screenshot:
  [image]
- Sometimes the SQL Server needs SSIS to be installed, so make sure you have it if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent few hours before finding this ultra-unusual bug... as it was not the `db_ssisoperator` on `MSDB` either the same on `SSISDB`, not a wrong login as suggested by the MS error I have received.
In my environment we are disabling the `public` server-role (by revoking all permissions assigned to it by default) so our proxy account didn't have the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission granted...

So by the look of it executing any SSIS packages (at least these deployed in the old fashion into MSDB) requires `VIEW ANY DATABASE` to be granted.

Answer (score 0):

If you will load a ssis package from a sql server, under a proxy account,
be sure to grant to that user db_ssisoperator on msdb database.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand what this message is. I think this is dtexec saying it can't read the .dtsx file.  Most of us don't edit .dtsx directly so if you are getting this message it means the ssis infrastructure in your company is creating inconsistencies. The practice in our org is to edit ssis packages directly without a solution using Visual Studio.  I had 3 packages fail with the above error message with various combinations of vs 2017/2019 direct and 2017 with a solution.  Then when I set SQL Server Version 2016 it was like a light went on,the package started to run. I tried Karl's below suggestion but the only 32/64 bit option I could find in vs 2017 Ent was debug which is not relevant at dtexec runtime.  So if you are dealing with a lot of ssis versions in your environment in both the client/development and the dtexec environment, try what I tried.  Obviously you can't implement 32 bit and SQL Server Version unless you have a solution (Add Existing Package to a new solution).